# Copy top 1000 rows from Production table to local machine SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

Can someone please let me know how do I copy the top 1000 rows from Production table to SQL Server on my local machine?

I have already tried the following on the production SQL Server:

1. Open SSMS, right click on SQL Server
2. Generate script and save to file.

But here file size is 5GB which I can't transfer to local because its has complete table dump, but I need just 1000 records.

Please let me know how do I do that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the appropriate network access and login privileges are present then you could configure a ['linked server'](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/linked-servers/create-linked-servers-sql-server-database-engine?view=sql-server-ver15) to the production DB and reference the table directly using 3 part naming convention.

Suppose the name of the linked server is 'ProdAConfig003' (from local to Prod) and the table is named 't' and the schema is 'dbo'.  Then from the local instance you could execute:

```
select top 1000 * from ProdAConfig003.dbo.t;
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the SQL Server import and export data. If you want, you can specify a query to retrieve the data (select top 1000 ..... ) and upload it directly to another sql server, a file, an excel, ....

if you really want a .sql file, you can then generate a script from the destination server using SSMS and generate script.

Comment: I tried Export, But I am getting error :- Error 0xc0202009: Data Flow Task 1: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80040E21.
An OLE DB record is available.  Source: "Microsoft Office Access Database Engine"  Hresult: 0x80040E21  Description: "Multiple-step OLE DB operation generated errors. Check each OLE DB status value, if available. No work was done.".
 (SQL Server Import and Export Wizard)